# Why do they get new identities if they know too much?

Tags: wargames-1983

In the 1983 science fiction film *Wargames*, US War office hides Dr. Stephen Falken and declared him dead. David learned that Falken himself died several years before from deteriorating health. Later he learned that Falken was still alive by chatting with Joshua, an online computer. On the ferry, Jennifer asks him:

> Jennifer: If he's alive, why'd the obituary say he's dead?
>
> David: He's not dead. He left. **When they know too much, they get new
>   identities**.

Comment: Presumably so no one can seek them out to find out what they know. But IDK if there's a definitive answer.

Comment: As @ApproachingDarknessFish points out.  It's a type of witness protection.    It happens in real life too, but not very often and usually just a name-change.  Joseph Pistone isn't reported dead, but he was given a new name (Movie Donnie Brasco is based on his undercover work).    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_D._Pistone    To actually declare someone dead seems unnecessary IMHO, but it makes for a good subplot in a film.

Comment: It would be hard to recruit if word got out about death being the retirement plan...

Comment: @HorusKol - I believe there was an episode of The Man from U.N.C.L.E. where a Thrush agent wanted to defect because death was the Thrush retirement plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

David's assumption is that eggheads like Falken (who know far too much to be left to simply lead private lives) are given false identities and their prior identities killed off. This protects them from hostile state actors like the Russians, who might kidnap them and try to make use of their knowledge.

Prof. Falken, for example, knows enough to neutralise the entire nuclear defence capability of the United States with a single phone-call. He would make a very juicy target which is why the government evidently "killed" him instead of just providing him with a new identity.

The [novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/74328.War_Games) (based on an earlier version of the script) has a little more detail in the conversation.

> *“And Joshua. So Joshua tells me that Falken isn’t dead! And he gave me an address. The Anderson Island address. Before I called you, I tried to call him, under his new name—Robert Hume. Unlisted. So, you know the rest.”
>
>   “But why would the obituary say he was dead?” Jennifer wanted to know.
>
>   “I guess it was a cover-up. Yeah, a convenient cover-up. Falken left. When these brilliant scientists leave and know too much, they give them new identities. Anyway, that’s what Joshua says.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[WarGames: A Novel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/74328.War_Games)</sup></sub>